# TypeError: defineCall is not a function at Sequelize.import

Tags: sequelize.js

Defined my User.js model as under but getting below exception

Error

> PS C:\Users\meghshyam\Documents\express_node_mysql_handlebars> node
>   server.js
>   C:\Users\meghshyam\Documents\express_node_mysql_handlebars\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:691
>       this.importCache[path] = defineCall(this, DataTypes);
>                                ^
>
> TypeError: defineCall is not a function
>       at Sequelize.import (C:\Users\meghshyam\Documents\express_node_mysql_handlebars\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:691:30)
>       at C:\Users\meghshyam\Documents\express_node_mysql_handlebars\models\index.js:23:36
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\meghshyam\Documents\express_node_mysql_handlebars\models\index.js:22:4)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\meghshyam\Documents\express_node_mysql_handlebars\server.js:16:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)

```
 "use strict";

 module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
 var User = sequelize.define("User", 
 {
 //timestamps: true,
 // id:DataTypes.INTEGER,
  username:{ 
  type:DataTypes.STRING,
  validate:{
    isEmail:true
  }
},
password: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  validate:{
    len:[6,12],
    notNull:true,
    notEmpty:true
  }
},
 role:{
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  validate:{
    notNull:true,
    notEmpty:true,
    isNumeric:true
  },
  }
 },

  {
 classMethods: {
 associate: function(models) {
  // Associating Author with Posts
  // When an Author is deleted, also delete any associated Posts
 // User.belongsTo(models.Student, {
 //   onDelete: "cascade"
 // });
//user has one teacher record
//   User.belongsTo(models.Teacher, {
//    onDelete: "cascade"
  });
  }
  }
  }
  );
return User;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normally caused by importing files that aren't Sequelize models in your `index.js`. Do you have anything in your models directory that isn't a model? In my case, it was because it was pulling in my test files as well as the models, which were in the same directory. Try adding another check into `index.js` where it builds the file list to exclude anything that ends with `.test.js` (or whatever the equivalent is for you).

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem, I didn't understant your method but for me worked this:

```
var CurrencyShop = require('./models/CurrencyShop.js')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
require('./models/Users.js')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
require('./models/UserItems.js')(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
```